# Придаточное отрывает второстепенный член от главного, к которому тот относится

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

1. *Он **перестал общаться** с одноклассниками, потому что они глупые и ленивые, **ещё в университете**.*
2. *Если в предыдущем примере **отрыв** второстепенного члена от того члена, к которому он относится, **при помощи придаточного предложения** выглядит неудачно, то в настоящем примере такой отрыв вполне приемлем.*

Помимо чувства языка, какие синтаксические признаки можно использовать, чтобы определить некорректность отрыва придаточным предложением или обособленным оборотом второстепенного члена от того члена, к которому он относится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**А. Общие положения**

1. Постановка вопроса мне кажется **не совсем корректной**. Здесь нужно говорить не об отрыве второстепенного члена, а об **интерпозиции придаточных предложений**, то есть на тему постановки придаточного в середину главного предложения.
2. Как известно,  все СПП делятся **на две группы** по виду связи между главной и придаточной частью: **присловные и присоставные**. Так, изъяснительные и определительные придаточные относятся к одному слову, а большинство обстоятельственных придаточных относится ко всему предложению.
3. Если придаточное относится к одному (опорному) слову, то его позиция **фиксированная:** оно располагается после опорного слова.  Интерпозиция придаточного рассматривается **только для обстоятельственных придаточных.**
4. Позиция придаточного (в начале, в середине, в конце) имеет определенные **смысловые оттенки**. В частности, интерпозиция придает придаточному **вставочное значение**, то есть фактически способствует его выделению так же, как при обособлении членов в простом предложении.
5. Интерпозиция придаточного возможна **для большинства обстоятельственных придаточных**, в то же время бывают исключения, а также зависимость от конкретного союза.
6. **Место вставки придаточного связано с общим понятием о порядке слов в простом предложении** (прямой и обратный). Так, при прямом порядке последовательность такая: подлежащее, сказуемое, прямое дополнение, косвенное дополнение. У обстоятельств позиция более свободна. На порядок слов влияют инверсия и актуализация предложения.
7. **И главный вопрос: в какое место в главном предложении можно вставить обстоятельственное придаточное?** Вот это уже решается в каждом случае конкретно, как и для обычных обстоятельств в простом предложении. Расположенное **между подлежащим и сказуемым,** придаточное имеет бОльшую выделительную способность, но надо учитывать и другие факторы.

**Примеры вставок**: Собрание, **поскольку докладчик не явился,** пришлось отменить. Петя, **чтобы никого не разбудить,** решил выйти через черный ход.

**Б. Ответ на вопрос**

1) **Он перестал общаться с одноклассниками, потому что они глупые и ленивые, ещё в университете.**

Сравнить: Он перестал общаться с одноклассниками из-за их глупости и лени ещё в университете. Два обстоятельства занимают свободную позицию, при этом фразовое ударение падает на второе обстоятельство (оно выделено в большей степени)

**Что не так в СПП?**  Скорее всего, придаточное кажется не на месте, так как смысл не угадывается в процессе прочтения. Мы читаем: Он перестал общаться с одноклассниками, потому что они глупые и ленивые... Кажется, что предложение закончено, а это не так

2) Второе предложение — это СПП с придаточным определительным, положение которого является **фиксированным**.

Answer (score 2):

Придаточное ***причины*** относится ***ко всему главному*** предложению и присоединяется союзом *потому что* , поэтому такое придаточное оформляем после главного:

***Он ещё в университете перестал общаться с одноклассниками, потому что они глупые и ленивые.***

*Придаточные причины обычно помещаются после главной части предложения, за исключением тех случаев, когда необходимо подчеркнуть причину или обоснование чего-либо и указать на следствие: Оттого что нельзя плакать и возмущаться вслух, Вася молчит, ломает руки и дрыгает ногами* (Ч.). [СПП с придаточными причины](https://helpiks.org/9-27662.html)

Придаточные ***определительные*** относятся ***к одному слову*** (иногда сочетанию слов) в главном, и поэтому придаточные определительные находятся чаще всего непосредственно после этого слова. Это второй ваш пример.